# Is there anything I can do to save my screenless Inspiron 6000?

Tags: laptop, display, formatting, dell-inspiron

So, my old Inspiron 6000 was working. It had no screen, but, I was able hook a monitor up to it and use it.

One thing, though, when it was booting up, BIOS would not show on the monitor. Only when it booted into Windows XP would it show anything on the monitor.

Anyways, so last night, I wanted to install a fresh OS on the Inspiron. I had virtual PC running on my other computer so that I could see the which options to select to freshly install an OS on the Inspiron. It seemed to work, but, I cannot see anything on the screen.
^ I know this sounds ridiculous.

So, I'm at the point now where the computer has been formatted and is either booting into windows, or, still somewhere in the setup. Is there anything I can do at this point?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing Fn + LCD/CRT on the keyboard.

Since that doesn't work, you can do an unattended installation of Windows and add the appropriate drivers to the answer file.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I've tried that but it doesn't turn the screen on.

Comment: I've edited the answer with another option.

Comment: Louis, is this what you had in mind? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc785644(WS.10).aspx

Can this be done without a floppy drive?